# Как подключиться из проекта VS C++/ CLI к Excel?

Tags: c++, .net, excel, c++-cli, com

Мне надо перемещаться по ячейкам таблицы в открытом Excel и модифицировать их содержимое. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В этой статье пример на C#, VB.NET, C++/CLI, Java:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/990914/Csharp-VB-NET-Cplusplus-CLI-Java-Work-With-MS-Ex

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с Excel необходимо добавить ссылку на библиотеку типов "Microsoft Excel ... Object Library" (на вкладке COM в диалоге добавления ссылки):

[image: reference]

Пример подключения к запущенному экземпляру Excel и изменения значения ячейки в активном листе выглядит так:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application^ app = nullptr;
    Object^ sheet = nullptr;
    Worksheet^ ws = nullptr;
    Range ^ cells = nullptr;
    Range ^ cell = nullptr;

    try {
        //подключаемся к активному экземпляру Excel
        app = (Application^)Marshal::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        if (app == nullptr) throw gcnew ApplicationException("Fatal error: Running Excel instance not found!");

        //находим активный лист
        sheet = app->ActiveSheet;
        if (sheet == nullptr) throw gcnew ApplicationException("Fatal error: No active sheet in Excel!");
        ws = (Worksheet^)sheet;

        //переходим в ячейку и устанавливаем ее значение
        cells = ws->Cells;
        cell = (Range^)cells->Item[1, 1];
        cell->Activate();
        cell->Value2 = gcnew String("Hello from C++/CLI!");         
    }
    finally{
        //очистка ресурсов
        if (cell != nullptr)Marshal::ReleaseComObject(cell);
        if (cells != nullptr)Marshal::ReleaseComObject(cells);
        if (ws != nullptr)Marshal::ReleaseComObject(ws);
        if (sheet != nullptr)Marshal::ReleaseComObject(sheet);
        if (app != nullptr)Marshal::ReleaseComObject(app);
    }

    Console::WriteLine("All done! Press any key to exit");
    Console::ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: К тем, кто спрашивает, как это компилировать. Приведенный код использует расширения С++ для .NET и **компилируется только в Visual C++** (с установленными инструментами C++/CLI). В GCC и других компиляторах собрать этот код не получится.